# How to start creating Mathematical models?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I know this is a quite general question , but I've always heard about creating mathematical models  in economics, social sciences, engineering,... And I would want to know what are the starting points and roadmap to understand what a mathematical model is and how to create them. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The last time I taught mathematical modeling we used *[Introduction to Mathematical Modeling](http://books.google.com/books?id=XPxrItVsXpQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=a+first+course+in+mathematical+modeling&source=bl&ots=4EcHhIII_M&sig=K1KZ1lq9OmZWj-aMKMdJiv5wg64&hl=en&ei=pVQKTeTAI4nUtQPioODDCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by Giordano, Fox, Horton, and Weir.  The first part of Chapter 2 contains a nice introduction to the modeling process.

A [search on Google books for mathematical modeling texts](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks%3A1&tbo=1&q=mathematical+modeling&btnG=Search+Books) should yield some more good results.

My [answer to a recent math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/probability-in-single-lane-traffic-flow-what-are-the-odds-of-choke-points-bein/11316#11316) also contains some discussion of the modeling process.

Answer (score 1):

COMAP, the Consortium for Mathematics and Its Applications has developed lots of materials at different levels that address your question:

http://www.comap.com/

Comment: Any online resources?

Comment: Sample downloads are available here: http://www.comap.com/product/samples/sampledownloads.html