# Where should I start from if I want to learn Mathematical Modeling?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am a student of political science and have basic knowledge of mathematics. But I need to learn Mathematical Modeling if I want to continue a research of mine. I'm willing to spend even 1 or 2 years behind it. But I cannot understand where to start. Could anyone help me in this purpose?

Comment: This could be helpful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14541/how-to-start-creating-mathematical-models?rq=1