# Modelling Traffic Congestion

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I noticed that on a road, if the number of cars reaching a certain critical stage, all the cars would slow down immediately.

Is there any theory/model that connects the number of cars $N$ with the average car speed $V$, and maybe with road width $R$  ( and other variables)?

Comment: You might be looking for traffic flow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_flow

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/